# How to start a new process on Websphere Liberty and make it in-dependable

Tags: java, perl, websphere-liberty, processbuilder

Developing a solution using ProcessBuilder to launch a perl script on Windows and Linux. The script is launched by a REST API. The Perl script does a stop/start on web server(Liberty Websphere). The REST API waits the result of such script. But since the server is shutting down, the rest api is disconnected and the perl script stops. 
I´m trying to find way out to start the perl script that does not depend on Webserver process. 
The main goals is to update a few resource on the web application by loading a patch file and then execute the perl script over this patch file.

Answer (score 1):

Dissociate the process from the parent (orphaning).

http://enwp.org/Orphan_process

> A low-level approach is to fork twice, running the desired process in the grandchild, and immediately terminating the child. The grandchild process is now orphaned, and is not adopted by its grandparent, but rather by init.

See the [Proc-Daemon source code](https://metacpan.org/source/AKREAL/Proc-Daemon-0.23/lib/Proc/Daemon.pm#L148) for details.

Comment: Thanks but it did not work. What I did was to breakdown the process into 2.
The GUI creates a new entrance on cron job.